# Pass Timer From Activty to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I understand that activity/fragment information passing has been asked a ton but I can't figure this one out.  I have an activity that (on a button click) start a Timer with a TimerTask and makes a fragment slide up from the bottom.  In the fragment that opens it closes on the press of a new button.  Want I want to have happen is make that button also stop that timertask.  How do I do that?

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

Timer timer;
protected boolean isTaskCompleted = false;
public boolean isTaskCompleted() {return isTaskCompleted; }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final CircularSeekBar sA = (CircularSeekBar)findViewById(R.id.bpm_scrubber);
    final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabbutton);
    final SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    final int electronic_sound = sp.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.high_metronome, 1);
    final int woodblock_sound = sp.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.low_metronome, 1);
    final int cowbell_sound = sp.load(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.cowbell, 1);
    final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("progress", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bpm_text);
    String test = settings.getString("sound_key", "1");
    final int lPInt = Integer.parseInt(test);

    sp.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int i, int i2) {

            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(sA.getProgress() > 0 && !isTaskCompleted()) {

                        timer = new Timer();
                        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                            public void run() {
                                if (lPInt == 1) {
                                    sp.play(electronic_sound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                                } else if (lPInt == 2) {
                                    sp.play(woodblock_sound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                                } else if (lPInt == 3) {
                                    sp.play(cowbell_sound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                                }
                            }
                        }, 0, 1000 * 60 / sA.getProgress());

                        Bundle args = new Bundle();

                        PlayFragment fragment = new PlayFragment();
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_up, R.animator.slide_out_up).add(R.id.relative_layout, fragment).commit();

                        isTaskCompleted = true;
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BPM cannot equal 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    sA.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new CircularSeekBar.OnCircularSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(CircularSeekBar circularSeekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bpm_text);
            editText.setText(Integer.toString(progress));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(CircularSeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(CircularSeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    int spInt = settings.getInt("progress_key", 0);
    editText.setText(Integer.toString(spInt));
    sA.setProgress(spInt);


    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!editText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                sA.setProgress(i);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit().putInt("progress_key", i);
                editor.apply();
            }

        }
    });

    final Spinner timeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.time_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.time_spinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    timeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

PlayFragemnt

```
public class PlayFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_play, container, false);

    FloatingActionButton fab2 = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fabbutton2);
    fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_up, R.animator.slide_out_up).remove(PlayFragment.this).commit();


        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: Your fragment should call a method in MainActivity that takes care of both removing the fragment AND stopping the timer. Very simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [Communicating with the Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity).

In short:

1. Create callback interface inside **PlayFragment**.
2. Attach **activity** as callback interface to private field in **PlayFragment**
3. Implement interface on activity and add code to stop timer:

   ```
   timer.cancel();
   ```
4. Inkove listener (activity) method inside `onClick` method.